# Java, Android / Stored values in an arraylist, but list is empty

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, null

I stored datas from the database to an arrayList called nameList.

Within the function 'get_spinner_info', the values are successfully stored within the nameList.

However, there is no value for nameList outside of this function.

The error code is
" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 ".

I really need your help.

```
public class my_Item {
    private Context context;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference datebaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    
    // Get the value from the database and put them in the 'nameList'.
    //In this code, I can successfully check the value within the 'nameList'.
    public void get_spinner_info(String brand, String item, String prod_key){
        datebaseReference.child(brand).child(item).child(prod_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("myValue").getChildren()) {
                    String prod_name = ds.getValue().toString();  
                    nameList.add(prod_name);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }


    // But the nameList is empty in this part.
    public void callFunction(final String brand, final String item, final String product_name, final String product_key, final int product_Num) {
        get_spinner_info(brand, item, product_key);
        Log.d("Spinner namelist :  ", nameList.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that piece of code compile on your machine? I don't see a class definition.

Comment: Yes, I only brought the code for the part with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_spinner_info` method starts and ASYNCHRONOUS data loading (registers lsitener), thus `onDataChange` will get called after `Log.d("Spinner nameList :  ", nameList.get(0));`

your data will be available only after `onDataChange` call, which may take some time. `get_spinner_info` just starts loading your data, doesn't means that all data will be available just after method call ends

put this on the end of `onDataChange` (after current `for` loop) to check your items available/present in array

```
for (String name : nameList) Log.d("Spinner", "name: " + name);
```

Comment: I applied this method, but the result is same. The output is successful, but the nameList still cannot be accessed only within 'callFunction'... But thank you for your answer

Comment: yes, it won't be present there, because all its code run immediately (currently two methods `get_spinner_info` and `Log.d` one after another) and `datebaseReference` takes some time, fetch data ASYNCHRONOUSLY and returns it in `onDataChange` - this is the first moment in which you can access data. stright inside `callFunction` data won't be present, thats how asynchronous data fetching works...

Comment: just put some `Log.d` on the end of `onDataChange` and you will see that data arrives few milisecs after `Log.d("Spinner namelist :  ", nameList.get(0));` (replace `nameList.get(0)` to `nameList.size()` to avoid exception accessing 0-index item in empty array at this moment

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization problem cause this kind of error

if you already have data do this

create interface class

```
public interface DataCallback {
    public void reciveData(ArrayList<String> nameList ,boolean isOk);
}
```

In your class **my_Item** call the interface like this

```
    public void get_spinner_info(String brand,String item,String prod_key,DataCallback callback){
            datebaseReference.child(brand).child(item).child(prod_key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.child("myValue").getChildren()){
            String prod_name=ds.getValue().toString();
            nameList.add(prod_name);
            }
            // here you should check if the result available or NOT to prevent null exceptions 
            if(nameList.size()>0){
            callback.reciveData(nameList,true);// true and false used to check data if available or null
            }
            else{
            callback.reciveData(nameList,false);
                            
                            }
            }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){

               }
                });
   }
```

Now when you call **get_spinner_info**  you need the callback Like this

```
get_spinner_info(brand, item, product_key,new DataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(ArrayList<String> nameList, boolean isOk) {
        if (isOk){
            /// you have all data recived
            Log.d("Spinner namelist :  ", nameList.get(0));
        }else {

            // no data available
            Log.i("TAG", "callback: No Data Available");
        }
    }
}););
```